# How to defer CommandLineRunner execution in Spring Boot test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, junit

I start worker threads in `CommandLineRunner` component

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    range(0, count).forEach(i -> taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
        while (true) {
            doWork();
        }
    }));
}
```

I want to test the correct functionality of workers in Spring integration test, but before that I need to insert some test data and prepare the scenario. Problem is the runner starts too soon. How do I defer the execution of `CommandLineRunner` in Spring integration test?

Comment: How about refactoring the whole task execution part to a separate component, doing your prep and then executing this separate component in your integration test? Then you'd have better control on what is executed when.

Comment: Yes, that's what I actually ended up doing

Comment: Post your test class, too